# Why GetFromJsonAsync can't parse the JSON but ReadFromJsonAsync can parse the same JSON response?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to send requests to my API project, the problem is that the `GetFromJsonAsync` method fails to parse the response JSON, but if I first get the response using the `GetAsync` method, and then do a `ReadFromJsonAsync` on that, it'll parse the JSON successfully, why is that?

This code doesn't work:

```
public async Task<OperationResult<LoginNextStep>> SearchByEmailOrPhone(string emailOrPhone)
{
    // This fails to parse the response body
    var result = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<OperationResult<LoginNextStep>>>
        ($"api/user/searchbyemailorphone/{emailOrPhone}", _jsonOptions);
    
    return result.Data;
}
```

This one does:

```
public async Task<OperationResult<LoginNextStep>> SearchByEmailOrPhone(string emailOrPhone)
{
    var result = await _client.GetAsync($"api/user/searchbyemailorphone/{emailOrPhone}");

    // But this one works, with the same JSON
    var jsonResult = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync
        <ApiResult<OperationResult<LoginNextStep>>>(_jsonOptions);

    return jsonResult.Data;
}
```

This is the `_jsonOptions` passed into the methods (Injected through the constructor into the class):

```
services.AddSingleton(new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() },
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say this, this only happens with a specific JSON returned from the API, I mean it's the same type as `ApiResutl` but for some weird reasons it fails to parse it, and in my API project, I'm using the `AspNetCoreRateLimit` package to throttle the spam requests, and in that package, if it decides to drop a request, it would by default return a line of text, but I could overwrite that and I added my own return type when it drops a request, and it's an `ApiResult` which is the default return type of all of my API's endpoints, (so I wanted that package to return the same result as other endpoints with 429 status code to indicate TooManyRequests).

This is the overwritten return type when it drops a spam request:

```
public class CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware : IpRateLimitMiddleware
{
    public CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IProcessingStrategy processingStrategy,
        IOptions<IpRateLimitOptions> options, IIpPolicyStore policyStore, IRateLimitConfiguration config,
        ILogger<IpRateLimitMiddleware> logger) : base(next, processingStrategy, options, policyStore, config, logger)
    {
    }

    public override async Task ReturnQuotaExceededResponse(HttpContext httpContext, RateLimitRule rule,
        string retryAfter)
    {
        var result = new ApiResult
        {
            IsSuccessful = false,
            MetaData = new MetaData
            {
                ApiStatusCode = ApiStatusCode.TooManyRequests,
                Message = "You sent too many requests!!!"
            }
        };

        var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() } };
        var jsonResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, jsonOptions);
        httpContext.Response.Headers["Retry-After"] = retryAfter;
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)ApiStatusCode.TooManyRequests;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResult);
        //return base.ReturnQuotaExceededResponse(httpContext, rule, retryAfter);
    }
}
```

To produce the issue, first I manually try to spam and the API will throttle my requests:

[image]

And then this is the response body as string, which is the same as the picture above:

[image]

The `ReadFromJsonAsync` could parse the JSON:

[image]

But the same request with `GetFromJsonAsync` fails, and it throws an `HttpRequestException` exception, (I think I did the same thing yesterday and it would throw an exception like CouldNotParseJson to ApiResult type ) anyways:

[image]

Exception details:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException   HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many
> Requests).   Source=System.Net.Http   StackTrace:    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
> System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.d__13'1.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter'1.GetResult()
> at
> Shop.UI.Services.Users.UserService.d__14.MoveNext()
> in D:\VS
> Projects\Didikala\src\Shop\Shop.Presentation\Shop.UI\Services\Users\UserService.cs:line
> 99
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
> System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsyncCore(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>,
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> Shop.UI.Services.Users.UserService.SearchByEmailOrPhone(string) in UserService.cs

It seems that `GetFromJsonAsync` tries to parse the JSON only when the response was successful, and it fails because of that, is there any way to make the `GetFromJsonAsync` parse the JSON response, whether it was successful or not? or I just have to do it in two steps, i.e. first `GetAsync` and then parse it with `ReadFromJsonAsync`?

Comment: When you say things like "fails to parse" and "doesn't work", it's always more helpful to have the actual response and the actual error than to leave people to somehow reproduce the problem themselves. Otherwise the only thing anyone can do is look up the source to these extension methods and start speculating based on the difference.

Comment: Post the JSON and the actual, full exception text. Not just the message, the full string returned by `Exception.ToString()`. You can get the same output if you click on the `Copy Details` link in the exception popup while debugging. Right now it's unclear if you get a parsing error or a server-side error response, or something else

Comment: Does the `GetFromJsonAsync` only work when the request was successful? I think that's causing the problem, is there any way to make it parse the response body even if the status code is not success? or I just have to do it in two steps, i.e. `GetAsync` and then parse it.

Comment: That sound very plausible. I think you'll have to use `ReadFromJsonAsync()` so you can parse both the success and the error response.

Comment: That's not a parsing error. That's the 429 error you wanted. If such problems are infrequent you can handle the specific exception. If you want to avoid the exception's overhead, you'll have to use the second snippet and check the response's StatusCode property and possible error payload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetFromJsonAsync` calls `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`, so it is expecting a status code between 200-299. On the other hand `ReadFromJsonAsync` doesn't.

See the [relevant code here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http.Json/src/System/Net/Http/Json/HttpClientJsonExtensions.Get.cs) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http.Json/src/System/Net/Http/Json/HttpContentJsonExtensions.cs).

Your message has a status of `429` so it fails.

You could write your own extension if you want.

```cs
public async Task<T> GetFromJsonAsync(string requestUri, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using (var response = client.GetAsync(requestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken)
    {
        var jsonResult = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>(_jsonOptions, cancellationToken);

        return jsonResult;
    }
}
```